# Spring boot loader cannot find resource

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I have a problem when I build my jar file with the `spring-boot-maven-plugin`, where I get the following error after running `java -jar my_file_name.jar <args>`:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at com.ryankshah.pdp.server.PDP.setConfig(PDP.java:39)
>           at com.ryankshah.pdp.server.PDP.(PDP.java:25)
>           at com.ryankshah.pdp.server.PDP.main(PDP.java:71)
>           ... 8 more

**EDIT**: I believe it is because I have not set the `resourceLoader` variable -- what should this be instantiated to?

Firstly, here is my project structure:

[image]

Here is my pom.xml (I run maven clean then install to build the jar):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.ryankshah.pdp.server</groupId>
    <artifactId>pdp_server</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <main.class>com.ryankshah.pdp.server.PDP</main.class>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.ryankshah.pdp.server.PDP</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ow2.authzforce</groupId>
            <artifactId>authzforce-ce-core-pdp-engine</artifactId>
            <version>13.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180813</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

And here is the main file where I am loading my resources:

```
package com.ryankshah.pdp.server;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.io.ResourceLoader;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class PDP
{
    // Server socket
    protected ServerSocket serverSocket;
    // Policy file loaded in config
    protected Resource configFile;
    // PDP Engine Object
    protected PDPEngine pdpEngine;

    protected static ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

    public PDP(int port, String config) throws IOException {
        setConfig(config);
        pdpEngine = new PDPEngine(configFile);
        System.out.println("Starting PDP Server...");
        this.serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println("PDP Server Started!");
    }

    public ServerSocket getSocket() {
        return serverSocket;
    }

    private void setConfig(String model) {
        switch(model) {
            case "RBIBA":
                configFile = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:config/rbiba_pdp_conf.xml");
                break;
            case "BLP":
                configFile = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:config/blp_pdp_conf.xml");
                break;
            case "CWall":
                configFile = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:config/cwall_pdp_conf.xml");
                break;
            case "RBIBA_BLP":
                configFile = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:config/rbiba_blp_pdp_conf.xml");
                break;
            case "RBIBA_CWall":
                configFile = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:config/rbiba_cwall_pdp_conf.xml");
                break;
            case "BLP_CWall":
                configFile = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:config/blp_cwall_pdp_conf.xml");
                break;
            case "RBIBA_BLP_CWall":
                configFile = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:config/rbiba_blp_cwall_pdp_conf.xml");
                break;
        }
    }

    public static JSONObject readReport(String deviceID) throws IOException {
        Resource r = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:reports/"+deviceID+".json");
        return new JSONObject(IOUtils.toString(r.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            final int PORT = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            final String CONFIG = args[1];
            PDP server = new PDP(PORT, CONFIG);

            while(true) {
                // Get client socket
                Socket socket = server.getSocket().accept();
                //clientList.add(socket);
                new ClientThread(socket, server).start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

*EDIT*: For further info, when I instantiate the PDPEngine, I use the following:

```
package com.ryankshah.pdp.server;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.ow2.authzforce.core.pdp.impl.BasePdpEngine;
import org.ow2.authzforce.core.pdp.impl.PdpEngineConfiguration;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class PDPEngine
{
    private PdpEngineConfiguration pdpEngineConf;
    private BasePdpEngine pdp;

    public PDPEngine(Resource configResource) throws IOException {
        File f = File.createTempFile("config", ".tmp");
        FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(configResource.getInputStream(), f);
        pdpEngineConf = PdpEngineConfiguration.getInstance(f, (String)null, (String)null);
        pdp = new BasePdpEngine(pdpEngineConf);
    }

    public BasePdpEngine getEngine() {
        return pdp;
    }

    public PdpEngineConfiguration getConfig() {
        return pdpEngineConf;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no `main`function in your code?

Comment: @HarryCoder Yes, there clearly is :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason that you are getting a `NullPointerException` is due to it is never instantiated your `resourceLoader` variable, you can instantiate by using default resource loader.

```
protected static ResourceLoader resourceLoader = new DefaultResourceLoader();
```